First order ode with tricky BC at infinity.
This is problem 94, page 41 from book "A book of problems in ordinary differential equations" by Krasnov,Kiselyov, Makarenko (very hard to find book, so no PDF online, and paper copies are very expensive)


In Latex
\begin{align*}
x^{3} y'-\sin \left(y \right) &= 1\\
y(\infty) &= 5\pi
\end{align*}
General solution is easy to find as it is separable. So just integration.
But I am not able to get the final solution for the BC given. Could someone see what is wrong with my solution?
Back of the book, page 301, authors give answer as
$$
y = 2 \arctan\left( 1- \frac{1}{2 x^2} \right) + \frac{9}{2}\pi
$$
I verified the book solution using the computer to be correct. Here is my solution.
Solve
\begin{align*}
x^{3}y^{\prime}-\sin y &  =1\\
y\left(  \infty\right)   &  =5\pi
\end{align*}
Writing the ode as
$$
y^{\prime}=\frac{1+\sin y}{x^{3}}\qquad x\neq0
$$
Shows it is separable
$$
\frac{dy}{1+\sin y}=\frac{dx}{x^{3}}
$$
Integrating gives
\begin{align*}
\int\frac{dy}{1+\sin y}  & =\int\frac{dx}{x^{3}}\\
\frac{-2}{\tan\left(  \frac{y}{2}\right)  +1}  & =-\frac{1}{2x^{2}}+c\\
\frac{2}{\tan\left(  \frac{y}{2}\right)  +1}  & =\frac{1}{2x^{2}}-c\\
\frac{2}{\tan\left(  \frac{y}{2}\right)  +1}  & =\frac{1-2x^{2}c}{2x^{2}}\\
\tan\left(  \frac{y}{2}\right)  +1  & =\frac{4x^{2}}{1-2x^{2}c}\\
\tan\left(  \frac{y}{2}\right)    & =\frac{4x^{2}}{1-2x^{2}c}-1\\
\tan\left(  \frac{y}{2}\right)    & =\frac{4x^{2}-\left(  1-2x^{2}c\right)
}{1-2x^{2}c}\\
\tan\left(  \frac{y}{2}\right)    & =\frac{4x^{2}-1+2x^{2}c}{1-2x^{2}c}%
\end{align*}
Hence
\begin{align}
\frac{y}{2}  & =\arctan\left(  \frac{4x^{2}-1+2x^{2}c}{1-2x^{2}c}\right)  +\pi
n\qquad n\in
%TCIMACRO{\U{2124} }
\mathbb{Z}
\nonumber\\
y  & =2\left(  \arctan\left(  \frac{4x^{2}-1+2x^{2}c}{1-2x^{2}c}\right)  +\pi
n\right)  \tag{1}
\end{align}
Applying IC gives, and taking limit $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\left(
\frac{4x^{2}-1+2x^{2}c}{1-2x^{2}c}\right)  =-\frac{4+2c}{2c}$ then the above
becomes
\begin{align*}
5\pi & =2\left(  \arctan\left(  -\frac{4+2c}{2c}\right)  +\pi n\right)  \\
& =2\arctan\left(  -\frac{4+2c}{2c}\right)  +2\pi n\\
\frac{5\pi-2\pi n}{2}  & =\arctan\left(  -\frac{4+2c}{2c}\right)  \\
\frac{2\pi n-5\pi}{2}  & =\arctan\left(  \frac{4+2c}{2c}\right)
\end{align*}
The range of $\arctan$ is $-\frac{\pi}{2}$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$. Hence we need
$\frac{2\pi n-5\pi}{2}$ to be in this range. This means $2\pi n-5\pi$ should
be between $-\pi\cdots\pi$ but not including the edge points. Value of $n$
which allows this is $n=-\frac{5}{2}$. (but $n$ should be an integer. There is
no integer solution. What to do?)
But if we continue, then we have
\begin{align*}
\arctan\left(  \frac{4+2c}{2c}\right)    & =0\qquad n=-\frac{5}{2}\\
4+2c  & =0\\
c  & =-2
\end{align*}
Hence the solution in (1) becomes
\begin{align*}
y  & =2\left(  \arctan\left(  \frac{4x^{2}-1+2x^{2}c}{1-2x^{2}c}\right)
-\frac{5}{2}\pi\right)  \\
& =2\arctan\left(  \frac{-1}{1+4x^{2}}\right)  -5\pi\\
& =-2\arctan\left(  \frac{1}{1+4x^{2}}\right)  -5\pi
\end{align*}
But this solution does not satisfy the ode.
Btw, neither Maple nor Mathematica are able to solve this ode !

@ClaudeLeibovici Take denominator as $(\sin \frac{y}{2} +\cos \frac{y}{2})^2$. We can rewrite it as $\frac{sec^2\frac{y}{2}}{(\tan \frac{y}{2}~ +1)^2}$. I think it's correct because we get something along the lines of $\int \frac{2}{u^2} du$

You can save a lot of algebra if you use the condition $y(\infty)=5\pi$ to determine $c$ in the equation
$$
\frac{-2}{\tan\left(\frac{y}{2}\right)+1} =-\frac{1}{2x^{2}}+c. \tag{1}
$$
Indeed, taking the limit $x\to\infty$ in both sides of $(1)$, we conclude that
$c=0$. Then, solving $(1)$ for $y$, we obtain
$$
y=2\arctan(4x^2-1)+2k\pi\qquad(k\in\mathbb{Z}). \tag{2}
$$
Since $\lim_{x\to\infty}\arctan(4x^2-1)=\frac{\pi}{2}$, the value of $k$ in $(2)$ that yields $y(\infty)=5\pi$ is $k=2$, hence the solution to the ODE is
$$
y=2\arctan(4x^2-1)+4\pi. \tag{3}
$$
In order to show that $(3)$ is equivalent to the answer given in the book,
$$
y=2 \arctan\left( 1- \frac{1}{2 x^2} \right) + \frac{9}{2}\pi, \tag{4}
$$
let $a=\arctan(4x^2-1)$ and $b=\arctan\left( 1- \frac{1}{2 x^2} \right)$; then
$$
\tan(a-b)=\frac{\tan a-\tan b}{1+\tan a\tan b} 
=\frac{4x^2-1-\left( 1- \frac{1}{2 x^2} \right)}{1+(4x^2-1)\left( 1- \frac{1}{2 x^2} \right)}=1
$$
$$
\implies a-b=\frac{\pi}{4} \implies 2\arctan(4x^2-1)=2 \arctan\left( 1- \frac{1}{2 x^2} \right)+\frac{\pi}{2}. \qquad\square\tag{5}
$$

Thanks, using implicit solution to find c first helps. But do you see where in my solution I went wrong? As sometimes I first solve for $y$ then find $c$ and that is what I did in this problem.  Your method is to first solve for $c$ from the implicit solution, and only after that solve for $y$, which I also use sometimes. But I'd like to know also where I went wrong in my steps.

After your Eq. (1) you took the limit $x\to\infty$ assuming $c\neq 0$. This gave you a wrong result. Redo your calculations after that point assuming $c=0$.
